# Using erase - is there a way to make this code less repetitive?

Tags: c++

This code deletes six lines from a file about a person from a contact list. This code works perfectly fine, however I don't know how to make this code less repetitive.

I use a `while` loop to push my lines inside a `vector`, and then use the following `for` loop to erase from the `vector`. At the end of the loop, I recreate the file again and push the remaining data into the file.

As you can see, I repeat `file.erase()` many times.

```cpp
std::cout << "Enter name of contact you would like to delete: ";
getline(std::cin, search); 

for(int i = 0; i < (int)file.size(); ++i)
{
    if(file[i].substr(0, search.length()) == search) 
    {                   
        file.erase(file.begin() + i); 
        file.erase(file.begin() + i); 
        file.erase(file.begin() + i);
        file.erase(file.begin() + i); 
        file.erase(file.begin() + i); 
        file.erase(file.begin() + i); 
        std::cout << "Success, contact deleted!"<< std::endl;
        i = 0; 
    } 
}
```

Could I use the following code to manufacture my code in a better, less repetitive, way?

```cpp
for(int remaining = 6; remaining > 0 && itr != file.end(); itr++, remaining--) {
```

Comment: No need for version-specific tags unless the question is about those versions in particular.

Comment: Honestly, if you had 1000 items to delete, I bet you wouldn't start to copy paste 1000 times.  That would be insane.

Comment: Yes you are right! I know, That is insane!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I really appreciate it! (=

Comment: You could have wrote an erasure loop , with the `i` value not changing inside the loop.  Of course the answer you accepted is the better way.

Comment: The thing is I have a loop already running, I tried loop, but did not get back the result I was expecting, Probably I did something wrong. Yes, The code from the comment below works fine. Please share your thoughts and code if you would have done it differently, I'll appreciate it!

Comment: Note: That `i=0;` at the bottom dooms the loop to a LOT of repetition. Every time you remove an item you start over again and reprocess all the preceding items that were not removed.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @Justin assuming 6 strings per contact, the loop should look more like this: `for(size_t i = 0; i < file.size(); ) { if (...) { erase... } else { i += 6; } }` Also, the `if` can be changed to `if(file[i].compare(0, search.length(), search) == 0)` No need to allocate a new `std::string` via `substr()` on each comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Remy! I really appreciate your comment here.  Can you please explain what does the 0 at the end does, what is it comparing to?

Comment: And also, where do you learn all this great stuff you know, I'm currently reading "C++ Primer". I found I have a passion for programming and tech, Love to know your thoughts!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of erasing the first element for 6 times, you can do:

```
file.erase(file.begin() + i, file.begin() + i + 6)
```

The two args in this erase method denotes the range [first, last) to erase. [Reference link](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'm starting to understad now.

Comment: There's not enough information in the question for this to be a well-thought-out answer. The type of `file` isn't given, so this answer is based on an apparently correct **guess**.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I will change the description. The type of the file is txt. (=

Comment: @Justin that's not what Pete Becker was asking about. What's the datatype of the `file` variable? You can't do any of what's in this answer or your question on a raw text file or a text file opened in a file stream. You could do it with a file read into a sequential library container, though.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for your feedback! All lines are strings,  What I did was, I pushed it first in a vector inside a while loop and then recreated the entire inside a new file with the same name. And used the for loop above to erase lines from the vector.

Comment: The answer is what I was looking for, But I'm thankful for clarifying this question.

Comment: I'll change it right now

Comment: I have changed the description, you can check it now, hope it is clear now, else please, I'll appreciate the feedbacks.